# Web server routing not working with Angular7

Tags: angular, .htaccess, webserver, angular-routing

I have created an angular 7 simple application with multiple routes

- home
- about
- contact

I've deployed to a web server and when I go to my website https://www.example.com (defaults to home component) and click on the router link to take me to:

- https://www.example.com/home
- https://www.example.com/contact
- https://www.example.com/about

This works fine as it resolves to index.html and then javascript does the routing.  However, when I attempt to load each of these pages directly I get a 404 not found (understandably as the web server cannot resolve the page).

My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php72 .php
```

What do I need to allow the web server to resolve my angular application in the expected way?

Thanks for any pointers in advance!!!

Answer (score 2):

And almost as quick as I posted, I discovered this:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php72 .php
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L]
```

Which worked for me!!